# How do I capture the output of a tty while still allowing sent characters to reach the correct destination?

Tags: logging, terminal

I currently have some systems that multiple people have access to for administration purposes. We've modified the history log so that we capture 2k lines of history per user to help aid in who has done what on the system. However, we would additionally like to capture all keyboard input when we (the administrators) log in, and log it to a file so we can see what changes were made to files once people go into vi to edit them. It will also aid us in documenting when we are going through a compile of software and the like.

How can I do this? CentOS 5.4 if it makes a difference.

Comment: You're probably going to encounter some issues with control characters and what not when raw logging terminals using vi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [tty log](http://search.cpan.org/~bbb/ttylog-0.83/ttylog) available.

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) and see how it would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When I have to log shell activity, I sometimes use a combination of [rootsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/) and central logging.